# SMART on FHIR @asymmetrik/sof-strategy introspectionUrl workflow

Tags: node.js, node-fhir-server-core

I am looking for sample about Asymmetric SMART on FHIR. Can someone help where/how the introspectionUrl generated using @asymmetrik/sof-strategy?

Answer (score 0):

The introspection url is part of an OAuth2 server that needs to be setup and configured by someone building the FHIR server. We use that module in both our repos (https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core, https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir), but it requires an external OAuth2 server. You can read a little more on that here, https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core/wiki/Access-Control#available-built-in-options, and here, http://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/.

If you are not integrating with someone else's SMART enabled OAuth2 server, you can check out projects like https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server. We used this server for one of our demo server's in the past and it will give you the endpoint's you need for `@asymmetrik/sof-strategy`.